# ng update Error request@2.88.2 and npm-packlist

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When **updating** my project to **Angular 10** getting an error from Angular CLI:

```
ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 --verbose
```

And here are the logs:

```
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.

An unhandled exception occurred: npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /private/var/folders/61/97bh4mb175n05ghhhm_8qsj0r54xf0/T/angular-cli-packages-aWYNdI/node_modules/npm-packlist/bin/index.js

npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/private/var/folders/61/97bh4mb175n05ghhhm_8qsj0r54xf0/T/angular-cli-packages-aWYNdI/node_modules/npm-packlist/bin/index.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Package install failed, see above.


node -v
v12.13.0

npm -v
6.12.0
```

Any ideas what may be the issue here and how to fix it?

Comment: It turned out someone has uploaded corrupt version of request@2.88.2 to the company's Nexus repository. Updating the version of `npm-packlist` which depends on it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check you app compatibility versions from
[update.angular](https://update.angular.io/) officially.

Also verify your npm cache by

`npm cache verify`

else clean by force

`npm cache clean --force`

Update :: Download Node officially from [14.15.4](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

then reinstall @angular/cli

`npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

Remove your project `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`

Reinstall node_modules.

Then execute `ng update @angular/core@latest @angular/cli@latest --verbose`

Please make sure your node and npm is update as per required angular docs.

Comment: I have been following the update guide and verified, cleaned cache, even deleted all node_modules including global. But still the same issue :-(

Comment: try to reinstall `@angular/cli@latest` globally then remove `package-lock.json` file then reinstall node_modules

Comment: @AlexanderBurakevych **Do not update npm using `nvm`, update it from your system package manager**